# How to Add New View in MWPhotoBrowser?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uidatepicker, mwphotobrowser

I am using `MWPhotoBrowser` To `display image and its Caption Text(Image name,Image date, Image Description)`. i added edit button in Navigation Bar when i Click edit button that's to be showing one View in that view i will change Image details.

i want To add View to Change The Caption Text in `MWPhotoBrowser` View. `I showed Image Detail(Name,Date,Description)` View when Picked up image in `Gallery /Camera`. But is it Possible to add a View in `MWPhotoBrowser`?

if possible  Please can any one help Me how can i create a new View

Comment: Use `MWPhotoBrowser` as navigation controller, and push new view controller to it when u want to hav extra view..

Comment: Oh ok but how can i parsing data to that View Controller

Comment: Pass complete `MWPhoto` object to the new view.. as it just points, just add the edits to it, inturn will reflect in the original one..

Comment: please give some sample code for Pass Complete MWPhoto object to New View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/MWPhotoBrowser-With-caption-editor.zip) is the sample code for the `MWPhotoBrowser` app with option for editing caption.

This suits your requirements, will work for you.

Thanks.

Comment: here i can edit the details but if i changed the text i didn't update in MWPhotoBrowserView

Comment: means, what u hav changed..?

Comment: i did changes in caption text in Edit View if i pressed save button. it didn't update on caption view in photobrowserview

Comment: is it not happening in sample code, or which u implemented..? have u checked the code in save button method.?

Comment: i implemented in my own code  this is save button code - (IBAction)saveCaption:(id)sender{
    
    NSString *temp_captiontext=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@,\n%@",self.edit_name.text,self.edit_date.text,self.edit_description.text];
    
    _photoObj.caption = temp_captiontext;
    
    
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    
}

Comment: in your `MWPhotoBrowser` class/view u need to reload in its `viewWillAppear` to reflect the data.. this is done in sample code.. check in ur implementation..

Comment: ya ur are correct i missed reload data in viewwillAppear thank you so much now its work great